# Talking in Space

Tags: acoustics, vacuum

Of course, it's impossible to speak in space due to the lack of a high enough density of atoms to allow for vibrations, however, is it possible for a person's vocal chords to vibrate in outer space without any air passing through?

Furthermore, if vocal chords can still vibrate in space - would touch another person's hand in space (assuming they are somehow able to survive without oxygen in the harshness of space) allow for communication through bone conduction?

I imagine it would work in a similar way of having two astronauts touch each other's suits and be able to communicate through vibrations in the suit.

Comment: Bone conducting audio is actually trending now: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCqisXxtego

Answer (score 1):

Air passing through is what *makes* your vocal cords vibrate.

Also, the words that a person speaks are not formed by his/her vibrating vocal cords:  It's formed by changes in the complex-shaped resonant cavity formed by the person's throat and mouth.  Note how, you can understand the words that a person whispers to you, but in whispering, the vocal chords do not vibrate at all.

With no air in the person's throat or mouth, there's nothing there to resonate, so no speech sounds would be possible.